# Laravel Date to javascript Error "Trying to get property 'date' of non-object"

Tags: ajax, laravel, date

I just followed some tutorial in youtube, however, I followed correctly the tutorial somehow it didn't work on me. The story is, I'm trying to get the name of the month in the timestamp (in MySQL) attribute (namely **created_at**). Hope someone can help me with this, it would be a great help.

```
public function getMonths(){
        $months = DB::table('users')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->pluck('created_at');

        $months = json_decode($months);
        if(!empty($months)){
            foreach($months as $unformattedDate){
                $date = new \DateTime($unformattedDate->date); 
                $monthsName = $date->format('M');
                return $monthsName;
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected to get the name of the month like Mar, Jun, Jan.. but it has an error saying " Trying to get property 'date' of non-object "

Comment: What is the output of `console.log( $month )`?

Comment: Can you try comment out ` $months = json_decode($months);` and see if it works?

Comment: an array like thhis: ["2019-05-14 07:36:56","2019-05-15 00:00:00","2019-06-05 00:00:00","2019-06-11 00:00:00","2019-06-12 00:00:00","2019-06-16 00:00:00","2019-06-18 00:00:00","2019-07-01 00:00:00","2019-07-01 00:00:00","2019-07-02 00:00:00"]

Comment: @SteD..did it and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, since you store the array of strings in JSON format, you don't need `->date`.

```
$date = new \DateTime($unformattedDate);
```